# Copy a file (not its contents) to clipboard from Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I'd like to copy a file to the clipboard so I can paste it into another application.

Is there a functional equivalent to pressing cmd+c on a file from Mac Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```bash
osascript -e 'set the clipboard to POSIX file "<FULL_PATH_TO_FILE>"'
```